# Windows reported maximum Frequency is stuck on 100% incorrectly

Tags: task-manager, resource-monitor, windows-server-2012-r2, turbo-boost

[Windows reported maximum Frequency is stuck on 100% despite cpu speed changing from 1.2GHz idle to 2.9GHz under load](https://superuser.com/questions/256921/what-does-the-maximum-frequency-number-mean-in-the-windows-resource-monitor) CPUid reports updated speed at regular intervals but the Windows Task Manager and Resource Monitor are not accurate. Windows Server 2012 R2, Intel Xeon E5-2640.

It works on other Windows 7 PC's with Intel i7/i5 CPU's. MS et. al. have no information regarding the bug.

Comment: Do you have the Hyper-V role installed?

Comment: Most likely it's Hyper-V. Don't worry about it, it's just cosmetic. The CPU still run dynamically