# What is "Maximum Frequency", why is it above 100% most of the time, and why is it so high when it should basically be idle?

Tags: cpu, clockspeed

Image of CPU according to WRM and Task Manager:

[image]

The above image is what WRM reports my Max Frequency to be of my CPU.

Why is it so high, and also why is the Speed on task manager higher than the 3.40GHz I assume to be the normal maximum?

As far as I know I've done nothing to overclock etc.

Comment: Your CPU has a boost frequency.  Its also possible you are overclocking your CPU without your knowlege.  Based on the information you have provided I can't say one way or another.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for your infor, would you happen to know how I would check if Im unknowingly overclocking?


 Also given that the computer is effectively idle, how concerned should I be by the fact this "maximum frequency" seems to be always around the 100% mark?


Is the "maximum frequency" a report on the actual maximum potential frequency (if so, why does it keep changing?)? 
i'm concerned that it might instead by something about consistent usage and therefore something is intensively using the cpu (and/or fudging the reporting)

Comment: I don't have enough information to help you determine that.

Comment: i7-3770 has a max turbo frequency of 3.9GHz on a single core, sounds overclocked to me

Comment: CPU utilisation does not necessarily have any relation to CPU max frequency (in those screenshots utilisation seems to be very low, as it should be when idle). Power management might do some things which affect the max frequency, but there's no need to drop that when the CPU is idle, as the max is the maximum _potential_ frequency, not the maximum used frequency within some time interval...

Comment: Related: [What does the “Maximum Frequency” number mean in the Windows Resource Monitor?](https://superuser.com/q/256921/358766)

Answer (score 8):

As stated in the comments, your processor supports [Intel Turbo Boost Technology](http://files.shareholder.com/downloads/INTC/0x0x348508/C9259E98-BE06-42C8-A433-E28F64CB8EF2/TurboBoostWhitePaper.pdf).
If you are not scared by (very slightly) technical papers, I suggest you to take a quick look at that paper.

Your CPU is the [3770](http://ark.intel.com/products/65719/Intel-Core-i7-3770-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz) which is designed to operate **safely**<sup>1</sup> at 3.40 GHz.
However, that CPU has four cores and as fewer cores are active the total thermal power decreases; so the engineers at Intel thought given the conditions they can safely increase the clock on the few cores that remain active.

Intel Turbo Boost basically increases the clock of active CPU cores up to 3.90 GHz as long as the power/thermal consumption remains under safe operating limits.
**Paradoxically this is only possible only the CPU is somewhat idle**, as explicitly stated in the paper linked before:

> For example, one
> particular processor may allow up to two
> frequency steps (266.66 MHz) when just one core
> is active and one frequency step (133.33 MHz)
> when two or more cores are active. Therefore,
> higher deep C-state residency (“C3” or “C6”) on
> some cores will generally result in increased core
> frequency on the active cores.

**Don't make the mistake of thinking that *a higher speed means a busier CPU***.
Quite the opposite!

As a rule of thumb, the CPU can use a higher clock for short periods or with low performance demanding<sup>2</sup> software.
The real thing is a closed-loop control:

> These
> constraints are managed as a simple closed-loop
> control system.
> When temperature,
> power or current exceed factory configured limits
> and you are above the base operating frequency,
> the processor automatically steps down core
> frequency in order to reduce
> temperature, power and current. The processor
> then monitors temperature, power, and current
> and continuously re-evaluates.

---

Intel Turbo Boost Technology is active as long as the Power profile is what is technically called *P0* (in *ACPI* jargon).
This means that if you enable "Max performance" in the settings of the OS, the processor will remain at 3.90 GHz on "idle" or "near-idle".

---

Regarding the measure of 4.14 GHz from task manager, I am **highly skeptical** about overclock.
Intel processors *don't have a direct way* to report the current operating frequency. In the same old paper linked at the beginning, Intel gives an algorithm to **estimate** the running frequency and says:

> Due to
> the way the BIOS and OS communicate Intel®
> Turbo Boost technology, software may never
> detect core clock frequencies above the base
> operating frequency

Being an estimate it can be off by some value, 4.14 GHz over 3.90 GHz is a 6% error which **to me is not enough to indicate any overclocking**, though I may be wrong here.

I'm not even sure the *3370* as an unlocked multiplier (should end in *k*?)

My guess is that Task Manager is doing its best to estimate the current frequency but it is not always accurate.

---

<sup>1</sup> In terms of current/power consumption and temperature.

<sup>2</sup> In the sense that not all functional units of the processor are used.

Comment: I also noticed this frequency>100% most of the times while on idle on my Windows 8.1, Asus laptop and this processor: AMD FX-7600P Radeon R7 12 computer cores 4C+8G 2.7 GHz. So I suppose AMD also uses the same boost technology? I've done nothing to overclock my CPU. Should it be a concern?

Comment: @dashakol Yes, it's called Core Performance Boost. Anyway, the general rule is that CPUs are tested to run a full speed for what could potentially be forever. So having your CPU running >= 100% is more an annoyance than anything else. Further, Windows is almost never really idle. As soon it detects low user activities, it starts doing its annoying weird manteinance tasks.